# How do I downgrade Cygwin's perl version from 5.22 to 5.14?

Tags: perl, compiler-errors, cygwin

I am trying to build a project but I keep getting this exception.

```
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\G{ <-- HERE / at .././tools/scpg
```

It is probably because of the perl version(I am using 5.22). How do I downgrade the perl version to 5.14? Is there any cygwin command for that?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I cannot ask the author to change the code(company code :P). Is there any work around for downgrading the version?

Comment: You could run it with `perl -X` (which disables all warnings). Why exactly can't you ask the author to change the code? Can you change your copy of it?

Comment: I did ask them(I am new to the team) Everyone just asked me to downgrade to 5.14.@KeithThompson

Comment: Don't mess with the system Perl. Instead, install your own Perl build (e.g. using `perlbrew`)

Comment: http://perlbrew.pl/ I tried the commands here. They dont seem to work.

Answer (score 4):

That's not an exception, it's a warning. See [perldiag](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html#Unescaped-left-brace-in-regex-is-deprecated%2c-passed-through-in-regex%3b-marked-by-%3C---HERE-in-m%2f%25s%2f):

> **Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/%s/**
>
> (D deprecated, regexp) You used a literal `{` character in a regular expression pattern. You should change to use `\{` instead, because a future version of Perl (tentatively v5.26) will consider this to be a syntax error. If the pattern delimiters are also braces, any matching right brace (`}`) should also be escaped to avoid confusing the parser, for example,
>
> ```
> qr{abc\{def\}ghi}
> ```

To fix the warning, you should update the code, not downgrade perl! Change

```
m/\G{/
```

to

```
m/\G\{/
```

Comment: Its company code. Sadly I cannot change it! Does perlbrew work with cygwin?

Comment: There's no need to downgrade at all; it's only a warning, which you can safely ignore until you decide to upgrade to Perl 5.26 (which won't even be released for another year). I don't know what you mean by "company code," but you're looking for a technical solution to a non-technical problem (i.e. your superiors not letting you fix deprecated code).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Does something special happen in v5.26 that allows unescaped braces in regex patterns?

Comment: @Borodin No, just the opposite: 5.26 is when the warning will become a syntax error. I hope the OP understood that part of my comment, I can see how it might be unclear.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Ah I see. It's the *"ignore until"* that bites. You got a reference for that?

Comment: @Borodin See the snippet from perldiag in my answer. Also [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quantifiers): "...in Perl v5.26, literal uses of a curly bracket will be required to be escaped, say by preceding them with a backslash (`\{`) or enclosing them within square brackets (`[{]`)"

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Got it. Thanks. That quote belongs in your answer

Comment: IIRC, policy is to deprecate for at least two major releases (5.22 and 5.24 in this case) before breaking something.

Answer (score 2):

There will come a day; not now, but soon; that your colleagues will have to fix their code

It was never right to involve an innocent brace `{` in all of this, but she was left alone without escape in a pattern of old and unfriendly specifiers

She was the beginning of something that could have -- should have been a number of things, but out of context all people could see was the curves. She needed to escape!

They need either to fix the malformed regex patterns or add `no warnings 'deprecated'` at the top of every non-compliant program. It will have to be done sooner or later, and I suggest that it is an *opportunity* for people to fix their code

Asking that you downgrade your installation of Perl is disgraceful

Comment: maybe, but asking that you use the same version of perl as others working on the same codebase is just plain sensible

Comment: @ysth in this case no. The correct code will work also in 5.14 and in the future version of perl